# Why rpmbuild -bb doesnt create rpm binary file?

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm trying to build a new rpm package for CentOS 6. Using my spec file I'm able to build src.rpm but for some reason I`m not able to create rpm binary file.

This is my spec file:

```
Name:           mc
Version:        4.8.11 
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Midnight Commander

Group:          System Environment/Base
License:        GPLv2
URL:            http://ftp.midnight-commander.org/mc-4.8.11.tar.bz2
Source0:        mc-4.8.11.tar.bz2
Buildroot:      <dir>
BuildRequires:  glibc-utils
Requires:       sland

%description
This is simply file manager for linux.

%prep
%setup -q


%build
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}

%check
make check

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

install -m 755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_sbindir}
ln -s /home/rpmbuilder/bin/mckonrad $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_sbindir}

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc


%changelog
```

`rpmlint` command showing this:

```
[rpmbuilder@localhost SPECS]$ rpmlint mc.spec
mc.spec: W: invalid-url Source0: mc-4.8.11.tar.bz2
0 packages and 1 specfiles checked; 0 errors, 1 warnings.
[rpmbuilder@localhost SPECS]$
```

I executed command:

`rpmbuild -bb mc.spec`

and I cannot find *.rpm file in RPMS folder.

I suspect that something is wrong with my mc.spec file.

Would be perfect is somebody could help me.

Answer (score 2):

You have no entries in the %files section of your spec file.

Try adding an entry in %files and then rebuilding.